# Route to Bootstrap modal in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, model, bootstrap-modal

When a form on my Laravel site is successfully submitted I want it to direct to a Bootstrap modal which displays some results from it and gets further information from the user - at some later point this modal will also contain a Stripe payment element and this "temporary" route will redirect to a final invoice route. However I'm currently stuck on the first step - although the modal triggers fine using Bootstrap's `data-bs-*` helpers, the Submit still triggers the loading of the new route, and I'm not sure how to route to a modal in my routes file.

These are my current routes for the page, the first one for GET and a duplicated one for POST, both of which make use of route-model binding so that I don't have to use any controllers:

```
Route::get("/manufacturers/{manufacturer:slug}", function (Manufacturer $manufacturer) {

if (Manufacturer::where('slug', $manufacturer->slug)->exists()) {

    if (view()->exists("manu.$manufacturer->slug")) {
        return view("manu.$manufacturer->slug", [
            "manufacturer" => $manufacturer
    ]);
    }

    return view("manu-not-found", ["manufacturer" => $manufacturer]); 
    }

    abort(404);
});    

Route::post("/manufacturers/{manufacturer:slug}", function (Manufacturer $manufacturer, Request $request) {

if (Manufacturer::where('slug', $manufacturer->slug)->exists()) {
 
    if (view()->exists("manu.$manufacturer->slug")) {

    $radiocode = $manufacturer->$manuFunction($request);

    return view("manu.$manufacturer->slug", [
            "manufacturer" => $manufacturer, 
            "code" => $code
    ]);
    }
    
    return view("manu-not-found", [
        "manufacturer" => $manufacturer,
    ]); 
    }
    abort(404);

});
```

The binded (bound?) Model:

```
class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
   
    public function decodeManu($request) {

    $validated = $request->validate([
      "code" => ["required","min:4","max:30", "alpha_dash"],
      "email" => ["email","required","max:255"]  
    ]);

    $code = $validated["code"];
    $email = $validated["email"];

    ... 

    /* business logic that generates $result */
    
    return $result;
}
```

And the modal in my Blade that I'm trying to route to:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="precheck-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="precheck-modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-fullscreen-md-down">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Your data is available! </h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body alert alert-success">
          Your code is @isset($result) {{ $result }} @endisset 
           </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't route to a modal.  A modal should be triggered by javascript, so if it's part of a form submission, that should be done via ajax.

Comment: @aynber That makes sense now that you say it, thank you.